# delay loading of library in Shiny after UI appears, but before actually needed

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

If I call a package, like `library(tidyverse)`, in global.R it adds approx. 2 seconds to the initial launch of app on shinyapps.io. Note that this appears to be the case if no one has used the app recently (but not when there are concurrent users).

I don't need that package until an observeEvent is executed.

I can put the `library(tidyverse)` inside the observeEvent, but then that takes 2 seconds when time is of essence.

Can I load libraries just after the UI finishes loading but before the observeEvent?

Something like: if shiny app is idle (flushed?), then load a package?

Comment: `tidyverse` includes a lot of libraries. Maybe just load the ones you actually need. Otherwise, you can put the library call inside the reactive observe function `if(!"tidyverse" %in% .packages()) library(tidyverse)`

Comment: (1) Loading `library` in an `observeEvent` seems odd to me, is there a reason you don't load it globally, before the UI? I know it'll delay the initial startup a little, but I don't know that you can avoid that. (2) I *strongly* concur with @IanCampbell. `tidyverse` as a meta-package is okay for simplicity when learning R or working on the console, but if you don't need all of its packages, then you're wasting the time needlessly.

Comment: @IanCampbell, depending on the impact, perhaps in an `observe` (so it is aggressive, not lazy), possibly with `invalidateLater` to get it to load a second or three after everything starts up.

Comment: @r2evans I have never used `invalidateLater`, but based on the documentation, that sounds like an excellent option.

Comment: I was just using tidyverse as an example... I have multiple rather complicated individual libraries that are still large and time consuming. A profile on my machine shows that the necessary libraries are slowing things down by almost 5 seconds. The reason I do not want to do this globally is the time problem. But if the global load only happened once in, say, a month, then I'd be fine with it...but I believe if the app has no users for a while, it will have to reload.

Answer (score -1):

Below is one way to do it that relies on `onFlushed`, but I'd like to see if someone finds something better (like using `invalidatelater` as mentioned in the
comments above).

I'm not sure what `onFlushed` does, but here's what the documentation says:

```
"onFlushed registers a function that will be called after Shiny flushes the reactive system."
```

I think that a flush means that all the other reactives are "resolved." In my case, the UI appears far quicker and allows user input BEFORE tidyverse is loaded, which makes the app more responsive to begin with.

Put the below in the server:

```
values <- reactiveValues(finished.init = FALSE)

session$onFlushed(function() {
  values$finished.init <- TRUE
 })
  
observe({
  req(values$finished.init)
  library(tidyverse)
  #any other libraries you'd like to load after initial flush
  })
```